# Plot multivariabe function using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create a figure with three axes and a curve like in the image below
[image]

However, i cannot see a way to add multivariable functions in the TikZ plot.

Comment: Have a look at `pgfplots`

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you add your first try: [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) and the function .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{pgfplots}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot3[domain=0:720,surf] {sin(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*EDIT*

In response to OP's comment:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{pgfplots}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot3[domain=0:1,surf] {sin(720*(x+y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want a function of three variables then you get a four-dimensional object, which cannot be drawn in three-dimensional space.

[image]

Comment: thank you. However three dimensional, the function still consist of only one variable. I was thinking more in the lines of f(x,y,z) = sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2) or similar

Comment: see updated answer